# How to deploy Node app via Jenkins to Ubuntu(18.04)?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, deployment, continuous-delivery

I'm a very beginner in Jenkins and afraid that I ask you something not clear with a weird question.

I'd like to deploy my simple node app server to Ubuntu via Jenkins.

I tried to write a command in Build at a Job as below :

```
./script/deploy.sh
```

deploy.sh file is here.

```
#!/bin/sh
EOF
 npm install
 pm2 restart app.js --name="myApp"
 exit
EOF
```

When I run a build, it stucked with error as

```
FATAL: Could not checkout 0d563b394d506e8450833e9b36d7a7b44834df39
```

The Full log of Error.

```
 > git checkout -f 0d563b394d506e8450833e9b36d7a7b44834df39
FATAL: Could not checkout 0d563b394d506e8450833e9b36d7a7b44834df39
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 0d563b394d506e8450833e9b36d7a7b44834df39" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/HISTORY.md': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/LICENSE': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/README.md': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/index.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/package.json': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/cookie.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/session.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/store.js': Permission denied
HEAD is now at 0d563b3 commit

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$900(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2341)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 0d563b394d506e8450833e9b36d7a7b44834df39
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2365)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1242)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1816)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

My questions :

**1. How to deploy a node app to ubuntu via Jenkins.**

- Is my way right? or another way is better?

**2. What error is it as following the log.**

Answer (score 2):

This article very clearly explains how to deploy a nodejs app using Jenkins:

https://blog.couchbase.com/create-continuous-deployment-pipeline-nodejs-jenkins/

Answer (score 1):

delete your job, create a new one, add a step clean workspace as the first step of your job. with pipelines it is `cleanWs()`. see plugin doc here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have a GIT permissions issue (you cannot write to files and or directory):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774397/git-push-error-unable-to-unlink-old-permission-denied

```
stderr:
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/HISTORY.md': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/LICENSE': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/README.md': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/index.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/package.json': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/cookie.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/session.js': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'node_modules/express-session/session/store.js': Permission denied
```

Comment: Thought I didn't assume the permission problem because when I checked the webhook in Github, showed me verified.

Comment: The problem had been happening after a Jenkins job runs few times.